# Update ShapeLayer in UIView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, cashapelayer

I am trying to draw a CAShapeLayer in a UIView and update the strokeStart and strokeEnd in response to a changing variable. The shape layer is created and drawn on screen as it should, but I am not able to update it.

My code:

```
//drawing shapeLayer on screen
- (void)setFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
    [super setFrame:frame];

    shapeLayer = [CAShapeLayer layer];

   UIBezierPath *variometerGuage = [UIBezierPath bezierPath];   
   [variometerGuage moveToPoint:CGPointMake(25, 5)];
   [variometerGuage addLineToPoint:CGPointMake(25, 200)];
   [shapeLayer setPath:variometerGuage.CGPath];

   shapeLayer.strokeStart = 0;
   shapeLayer.strokeEnd = .5;
   shapeLayer.strokeColor = [UIColor colorWithWhite:0.5 alpha:1.0].CGColor;
   shapeLayer.lineWidth = 10;
   [shapeLayer setLineCap:kCALineCapButt];

   [self.layer addSublayer:shapeLayer];
}
```

The following code is called from the View Controller. I know it is being executed, but the UIView is not updated.

```
- (void)updateVariometerGraphocsWithLift:(float)vario {

    shapeLayer.strokeStart = vario; //vario being a number between 0 and 1

    [shapeLayer setNeedsDisplay];
    [self.layer addSublayer:shapeLayer];
    [self.layer setNeedsDisplay];
    [self.layer setNeedsLayout];
}
```

Any ideas?

Comment: don't you need to remove the previously added sublayer before adding the new one?

Comment: @cud, yeah, if the first shape was full, and subsequent additions were less, then the duplicated backing layers would hide the change.  To your point, he needs to store the layer as a property, and directly change that.

Comment: @chrisco, Could you please give me an example of how to do that?? I don't quite get what you are advising me to do.. Much appreciated!

Comment: Just make shape layer an instance property and only add it once.  Thereafter, you can update the start and end as you have been doing.  Your current code is adding new layers, but you can't see subsequent partial layers as they are layered the existing paths behind.  For a simple illustration, keep your code as is, but change the start and end values and see how the path changes (and only call it once).  You can then deduce that the start/end logic fine, but you need to update the existing layer instead of adding new ones.